# newbie developer: where can I print out the cocoa framework from my mac?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, frameworks

Other answers have said to use "Capabilities" in Xcode 6 to get a listing of the cocoa framework but I can't find any such thing in Xcode 6 menus. Is this a correct answer and if not how can I print out the cocoa framework so I can see what objects and methods are declared?

thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'print out'?

Comment: get a listing of the framework on a printer for reference

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your question, but anyway Apple provides to us a well explained documentation that you can read: [Mac Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/)

For example you can read the [NSView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004149/) or all the others Frameworks References.

If you just  need the interfaces you could also from Xcode `cmd+click` on the class name to see the class interface.

But if you are also looking for private APIs, you should dump the Frameworks yourself or search them on GitHub, from who already did it for you.

Comment: Thanks! I realize now it was a dumb question from a newbie.